# Arduino GSMShield

Tags: c++, arduino, gsm, arduino-uno

I've been working on a project with arduino UNO and GSM Shield.

I'm uploading to Internet data every 30 minutes from a maxbotix sensor. Code hangs and loops continuously with the serial monitor showing **gsm.begin() waiting for reply**.

I have read very carefully all the related forums and rewrote the library file **GSM3ShieldV1AccessProvider.cpp** as per http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=233137.0

Unfortunatelly this doesn't solve the problem. With gsm debug set to true it stucks on the the infamous AT%13%   (post http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=233137.0)

This is driving me mad as it ruins the whole project. 
Anyone has find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If Arduino stucks at this point that's because the modem is answering with ERROR to the AT command and it doesnt continue to AT+CPIN, AT+CGREG ...
So, obviously it's not a SIMcard problem neither a APN problem

Have you try to update the GSM library?
Please, show me the debug log you are getting

```
GSM gsmAccess(1);
```